# Simple system events AppleScript won't work in NSAppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

This works fine in the Apple Script app:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using command down
```

But in NSAppleScript it errors on "key code."  Quotes are properly escaped, several different syntaxes all do the same thing.  There is preceding stuff in the application to activate the app receiving the keystroke but that isn't needed in the project, and if it's there it compiles, so clearly NSAppleScript is picking up the dictionaries.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Application is sandboxed with cross-scripting entitlement, there was no bundle ID for System Events application.

Answer (score 0):

I can run this code with no errors. Both the result and errorDict log as null, so no problems. You must have some other issue... it's not the applescript.

```
NSString* cmd = @"tell application \"System Events\" to key code 124 using command down";
NSAppleScript* theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:cmd];
NSDictionary* errorDict = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor* result = [theScript executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
[theScript release];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
NSLog(@"error: %@", errorDict);
```

Comment: Code is identical to yours but for variable names, what I get from debugger is this:

`2012-11-28 11:25:50.325 **********[10521:303] script = tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using command down
2012-11-28 11:25:50.817 **********[10521:303] NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = A identifier can’t go after this property.
2012-11-28 11:25:50.817 **********[10521:303] NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = -2740
2012-11-28 11:25:50.818 **********[10521:303] NSAppleScriptErrorRange = NSRange: {36, 8}`

Counting characters, it's marking "key code" as the identifier in question